# ETIMEOUT from Tedious in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, tedious

## Setup

- AWS Lambda (**3s timeout**)
- NodeJS 12.x
- `mssql` 2.6.1
- `tedious` (dependency of `mssql` and so it installs tedious 6.7.0)
- SQL Server DB in RDS (db.t3.small)

I'm also dealing with a fair bit of traffic, with roughly 1k invocations per minute.

## Problem

Most of the time the Lambda executes just fine.  Roughly 0.35% of the time the Lambda throws an error.  The logs look like this:

[image: CloudWatchLogs]

In the screenshot you can see that the function STARTs, prints some debug info, then throws an error, ENDs, and REPORTs.

While this is a "timeout" error, the error message says,

> RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms

This confuses me because as you see in the REPORT log, the invocation time was just 255.33ms total.

## Question

The obvious question is **how does something timeout after 15 seconds in just 255ms?**  Is this an issue with `tedious`, `mssql`, my code, or something else?  If my code is relevant to the question please let me know and I can add it.  I assume the code is basically functional because it works > 99% of the time.

#### Failed Theories:

- The logs are interleaved and the errors are not from the 225ms invocation. That's wrong because in the screenshot the request ID's match up.
- There's an intermittent error connecting to the DB, possibly a DNS issue.  I have seen very rare `EAIAGAIN` DNS errors when resolving the DB host, but that doesn't seem to match with the steadiness of this error.
- I didn't spot anything super helpful in the GitHub issues for Tedious.

## Full Error

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "RequestError",
        "errorMessage": "Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
        "code": "ETIMEOUT",
        "originalError": {
            "errorType": "RequestError",
            "errorMessage": "Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
            "code": "ETIMEOUT",
            "message": "Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
            "stack": [
                "RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
                "    at RequestError (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:32:12)",
                "    at Connection.requestTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1212:46)",
                "    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1180:14)",
                "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)",
                "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"
            ]
        },
        "name": "RequestError",
        "number": "ETIMEOUT",
        "precedingErrors": [],
        "stack": [
            "RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
            "    at Request.userCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:429:19)",
            "    at Request.callback (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js:56:14)",
            "    at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:2407:20)",
            "    at Connection.dispatchEvent (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1279:15)",
            "    at Parser.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1072:14)",
            "    at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)",
            "    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)",
            "    at Parser.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:37:14)",
            "    at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)",
            "    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
    ]
}
```